Speeding up Django's total record count calculation for a site with 20 million records MySQL
I've encountered a problem with my Django website. Given that my database contains more than 20 million records, the operation of counting the total number of data (count) becomes extremely slow. I am using the following queries:
company_count_query = f"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cs.OGRN) AS total_companies {company_from_clause} WHERE {company_match_condition} {email_condition} {capital_condition} {date_condition} {company_okved_condition}"

ip_count_query = f"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ip.OGRNIP) AS total_ips {ip_from_clause} WHERE {ip_match_condition} {imail_condition} {ip_okved_condition}"


How can I optimize these queries or use other methods to speed up the calculation of the total number of records?
Thank you for your help!
I tried to optimize the query structure by adding indexes to the columns on which filtering is performed, hoping to improve the performance of the counting operation. I expected that this would reduce the query execution time and speed up the data processing. However, in practice, the query execution time remained high and the counting operation still takes too long.

There are a lot of things to consider here. If you post the models involved people can get an idea on how to help you.

I don't use models, I have a direct connection to the database. Or still using models can be faster and more efficient?

It might involve a bit of development work, but can you maintain a running total somewhere?

Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE for the table, plus the generated SELECT.
